# Variable names for Contact Information bits

Tags: naming, variables

I am in the middle of refactoring code and would like to get some ideas on variable naming so that my new names clearly represent the data they hold.

I have a class called `ContactMethod` which makes sense to me; each instance is a different way to contact someone. My problem comes when naming the properties of `ContactMethod`. For example, one instance might be a Fax number of 555-555-5555 while another could be an Email address of bob@email.com; I've got a property called `contactMethodType` to hold the values "fax" or "email", but I don't know what to call the "555-555-5555" or "bob@email.com" part. Has anyone here created a good generic name for this piece of contact information?

*(PS - the old convention was to call it a "Phone" with fields "phoneType" holding the "fax"/"email" value and "phoneId" holding the number/address. Yuck.)*

Comment: `ContactInformation` is my best guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my mind, if you can't think of a meaningful name for an abstraction, it means that the abstraction is probably not going to help you.   Out of curiousity why does calling it *ContactMethod* help you or make more sense than a separate *Phone* and *Email* class?

Abstractions are supposed to provide you with common behaviour for entities which are similar.   I don't know anything about the particular problem which you're trying to solve, but off the top of my head I can't really see much in common between a phone number and an e-mail address.    For example, your validation will probably follow totally different rules, and the way in which you use an e-mail address to contact someone (sending them an e-mail) is different to the way you'd contact them with their phone number.
(Also, the fact that you are storing a separate `ContactType` suggests your code may be packed full of *`if(type == phone) else if(type == email)`* etc anyway).

IMO it is ok (and sometimes better/desirable) to create separate data/entities for things which are logically different.  Sometimes you can try too hard to find a common one-size-fits all solution which ultimately doesn't make your life any easier

Comment: To answer your first question, the main reason that we grouped them under `ContactMethod` was because they both existed in the same database. Our DBAs are...quite resistant to changing the schema, so I guess I'm just trying to fit round pegs in square holes.

Comment: "I can't really see much in common between a phone number and an e-mail address" Our system allows users to setup automatic notifications via different contact methods. That's really the common concept between the two, but I agree that they would benefit more from an inheritance approach where `Phone` and `Email` are children of `ContactMethod` rather than different instances of the same class